# AngularSplitModule CSP issue - refused to load image because violating CPS directive: "default-src 'self'"

Tags: angular, content-security-policy, angular-module

In my app i export the AngularSplitModule in a shared module so i can use it when needed in different feature modules.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angul`enter code here`ar/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AngularSplitModule } from 'angular-split';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
  ],

  exports: [
    AngularSplitModule,
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

After the building process i have the issue that the little icon on the gutter can not be loaded due to an CSP violation.

[image]

The error msg: 
[image: Refused to load the image '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.]

Can somebody point me into the right direction? Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see your CSP configuration, but you'll need to set `img-src 'self' data:;` to allow data uri images.

See `<scheme-source>` in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/img-src#Sources